# Blocking more folders and applications

Tags: vb.net

As you can see here I block the directory called "cleo". If I have it in my folder I can't click connect. How can I check if, for example, "Cleo", "Images", "Logs" exist in browsed file. I don't think making multiple If statements would be good, is there any other way?

```
    Private Sub connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles connect.Click
        Dim cleoPath As String
        Dim filePath As String
        filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, "gta_sa.exe")
        cleoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, "cleo")

        If File.Exists(filePath) Then
            If Directory.Exists(cleoPath) Then
                MsgBox("Pronasli smo cleo fajl u vasem GTA root folderu. Da se konektujete na server morate ga obrisati.")
            Else
                Dim p() As Process
                p = Process.GetProcessesByName("samp")
                If p.Count > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Vec imate pokrenut SAMP - ugasite ga.")
                Else
                    Try
                        Dim prozess As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("samp")(0)
                        prozess.Kill()
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAMP", "PlayerName", TextBox1.Text)
                    Process.Start("samp://193.192.58.55:7782")

                    Dim client As New TcpClient
                    client.Connect("193.192.58.55", 10924)
                    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)
                    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
                    stream.Write(sendbytes, 0, sendbytes.Length)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Da se konektujete morate locirati GTA San Andreas folder.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to do. You have multiple folders like Cleo and would like to "not connect" if ever there are present in the GTA directory ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use extension methods combined with a directoryinfo to check if any of a list of directory exists. Depending of if you just want a true/false return or if you need to process each directories (for instance, by adding a custom message with the name of the folders that prevent your application from continuing.

```
Public Module DirectoryInfoExt
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function AnyExists(DirInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo, ParamArray Directories As String()) As Boolean
    Dim MyPath As String = DirInfo.FullName.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\"
    Return Directories.Any(Function(Dir) IO.Directory.Exists(MyPath & Dir))
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function GetExistingDirectories(DirInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo, ParamArray Directories As String()) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim MyPath As String = DirInfo.FullName.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\"
    Return Directories.Where(Function(Dir) IO.Directory.Exists(MyPath & Dir))
End Function
End Module
```

An example the boolean return.

```
Dim BaseDirectory As String = "C:\Games\GTA"
    Dim GamePath As New DirectoryInfo(BaseDirectory)

    ' Will not give the specific path that exists, only a Boolean if any of theses folder are found
    Dim ModsFound As Boolean = GamePath.AnyExists("Images", "Cleo", "Logs", "SomeFolder\Subfolder")

    If Not ModsFound Then
        'Connect
    Else
        ' Do something
    End If
```

An example using the list return to generate a custome message prompt stating the name of the specific folders found.

```
'This version gives a list instead.
    Dim ModsFoundList As IEnumerable(Of String) = GamePath.GetExistingDirectories("Images", "Cleo", "Logs", "SomeFolder\Subfolder")
    Dim HasMod As Boolean = ModsFoundList.Count > 0

    If HasMod Then
        EvilModdedUserPrompt(ModsFoundList)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Here, since HasMod is false, we can proceed with connection.
    ' Do connection
```

As for the EvilModdedUserPrompt method

```
Public Sub EvilModdedUserPrompt(ModsFoundList As List(Of String))
    Dim OutputMessage As New Text.StringBuilder
    OutputMessage.AppendLine("The following mods have been detected on your system:")
    For Each Moditem As String In ModsFoundList
        OutputMessage.AppendFormat("- {0}", Moditem)
        OutputMessage.AppendLine()
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(OutputMessage.ToString)

End Sub
```